# Flutter - Load Google Map Markers from Firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-maps, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing a Flutter app and one of the functions is a map with locations. I made a database with the locations in Firestore but I am unable to load the markers.

I don't get any errors and it looks like the app is connecting fine but it does not display the markers...

Can someone please help me with this?

Below my code, thank you!

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:hvd_test/styling/colors.dart';

class StationsMap extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _StationsMap createState() => _StationsMap();
}

class _StationsMap extends State<StationsMap> {

  bool mapToggle = false;

  var currentLocation;

  GoogleMapController mapController;

  Map<MarkerId , Marker> markers = <MarkerId , Marker>{};

  getMarkerData() async {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('hvd-stations').get().then((myMarkers) {
      if(myMarkers.docs.isNotEmpty) {
        for(int i = 0; i < myMarkers.docs.length ; i++){
          initMarker(myMarkers.docs[i].data , myMarkers.docs[i].id);
        }
      }
    });
  }

  void initMarker(specify , specifyId) async {
    var markerIdVal = specifyId;
    final MarkerId markerId = MarkerId(markerIdVal);
    final Marker marker = Marker(
      markerId: markerId,
      position: LatLng(specify['stationLocation'].latitude , specify['stationLocation'].longitude),
      infoWindow: InfoWindow(title: 'HvD Stations' , snippet: specify['stationAddress']),
    );
    setState(() {
      markers[markerId] = marker;
    });
  }

  void initState() {
    getMarkerData();
    super.initState();
    Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high).then((currloc) {
      setState(() {
        currentLocation = currloc;
        mapToggle = true;
      });
    });
  }
  
  @override  
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(  
      home: Scaffold(  
        body: Stack(  
          children: <Widget>[
            Container(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 80.0,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: mapToggle ?
              GoogleMap(
                onMapCreated: onMapCreated,
                myLocationEnabled: true,
                initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(target: LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude),
                zoom: 10.0,
                ),
                markers: Set<Marker>.of(markers.values),
              ):
              Center(child: 
              CircularProgressIndicator(),
              )
            )
          ],  
        ),  
      ),  
    );  
  }

  void onMapCreated(controller) {
    setState(() {
      mapController = controller;
    });
  }  
}
```

Comment: Is the Map loading fine in your app? Only the markers are not displaying?

Comment: My markers came from a Firestore database and I did something wrong in the implementation fase. I deleted the old implementation and did it again, everything is fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I did the implementation of Firestore I made a mistake with the placement of the document you add to your project. After reading the documentation I ran the implementation again with no issues and it is now working fine.